# How to 301 redirect back to a pretty link without creating an infinite loop in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I am doing a rewrite from `.htaccess` file to redirect pretty links to original URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^users/?$ /?status=users [NC,L,QSA]
```

which redirects my SEO/pretty link:

```
example.com/users
```

to the real URL

```
example.com/?status=users
```

Then again I want any search engine bot (or anyone else) who tries to get to

```
example.com/?status=users
```

to be 301 redirected to the pretty link

```
example.com/users
```

I know I could get the later part done using

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)status=users($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /users? [L,R=301]
```

But I can't use these two together as it gets into a never ending loop and the browser displays "redirected you too many times".

I think I get what the problem is here, but what is the solution? How do I  achieve both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)status=users($|&)
> RewriteRule ^$ /users? [L,R=301]
> ```

You just need an additional *condition* (ie. `RewriteCond` directive) on your *external redirect* that detects whether it is a direct/initial request from the user, as opposed to a *rewritten* request by your other rewrite directive.

One way to do this is to check the `REDIRECT_STATUS` *environment variable*. This is not set on the initial request, but is set to "200" (as in *200 OK*) after the first successful rewrite. So, you can check to see whether `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty in order to detect the direct request and prevent a redirect loop.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)status=users($|&)
RewriteRule ^$ /users? [L,R=301]
```

---

Another way is to check against `THE_REQUEST` *server variable*, which contains the first line of the initial request and does not change when the URL is rewritten. So, when requesting `example.com/?status=users` directly, `THE_REQUEST` would contain a string of the form:

```
GET /?status=users HTTP/1.1
```

This would allow you to have just one *condition*, as opposed to two as in the above, at the expense of perhaps a more complex regex. *(Implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.)*